# How do I setup MOQ to accept Any instances of a given Expression<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have the following interface that I want to mock:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    string GiveMe(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate);
}
```

With the following Poco:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am setting up my mock as:

```
[Test]
public void Run()
{
    var expectedPredicate = It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>();
    var mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mock
        .Setup(m => m.GiveMe(expectedPredicate))
        .Returns("Yo!");

    var message = mock.Object.GiveMe(p => p.Name == string.Empty); // throws
}
```

But I am getting:

> Invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the
>   mock must have a corresponding setup.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assign the result of `It.IsAny` to an intermediate variable, use it inline:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GiveMe(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>()))
    .Returns("Yo!");
```

If you look at the `Setup` method, it actually takes an `Expression` parameter, Moq analyses this to determine what your intention is, by assigning the result of `It.IsAny` to an intermediate variable, Moq will not see the `MethodCallExpression` it is capable of understanding and instead will see a `MemberExpression`.

This results in Moq actually performing an equality comparison between the actual parameter and `expectedPredicate` variable rather than the `It.IsAny` check.

Comment: Perfect, tnx for the Explanation